# Pandas pd.eval for 64.1*1e3

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently scrubbing some numbers and converting numbers if they are 66.1K to be 66100 using

```
df['number'].replace({'[kK]': '*1e3', '[mM]': '*1e6', '[bB]': '*1e9', },regex=True).map(pd.eval)
```

can replicate by just doing a simple `print(pd.eval('64.1*1e3'))`

However the return for 64.1K is 64099.99999999999.

Does anyone know why this happens? How would you use pandas to get 64100.0?

I have tested with 65.1K and it is the same result 65099.99999999999 but if I do 66.1K it equals to 66100.0.

Comment: well kinda but I know I can get it to 64100 by just using the round function. I'm really more curious as to why Pandas is behaving in the way it is.

Comment: Because of ```float``` representation in python

Comment: Could you expand on that? I don't really get it.

Comment: ah - this has an straight forward answer. https://floating-point-gui.de/ but thanks Grzegorz Skibinski